# HTML Python/Flask pass value (int)

Tags: python, html

sum_test.py

```
def sum_t(a, b):

    return a+b
```

main.py

```
@app.route('/test', methods=["GET", "POST"])
    def print_test():
        if request.method == "POST":
            # getting input with name = aa in HTML form
            a = request.form.get("aa")
            # getting input with name = bb in HTML form
            b = request.form.get("bb")
            result = sum_test.sum_t(a, b)
            return str(result)
        return render_template('test.html')
```

result is

> 1 + 1 = 11

but the result i want

> 1 + 1 = 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer should be self explanatory :)

`a = request.form.get("aa", type = int)`

You need to get the form fields as int values in order for them to be operated as mathematical expressions.